# jsoup crawler error when called inside a servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm trying to crawl flipkart product specifications and the code works fine when I run it as a java application. But when I call it inside a servlet it gives me an error:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;

Elements specs = null;

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(link).timeout(250000).get();
    specs = doc.select("table[class=specTable]");

    System.out.println(specs);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: 500 error loading URL http://www.......
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:414)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the userAgent?

Comment: ya. it works if i give some other flipkart link, like "flipkart.com" as the link string, just doesn't work for this page.

Comment: Update your question with the userAgent you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works when i use the userAgent mozilla.

```
doc3 = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(250000).get();
```